# How to find text blocks in a scanned document?

Tags: python, image-processing

I am trying to detect text in a scanned document by examining variations in the lightness of the scan collapsed vertically. Here's a sample of the input I would receive, with the lightness plot of each vertical pixel strip superimposed:

[image: Example]

Note: I've applied a Gaussian smoothing function to the data ~ 10 times, but it seems to be pretty wiggly to begin with. It is easy to see that the left margin is *really* wiggly (i.e., has many extrema).

**Problem**: I want to generate a set of critical points of the image.

I've resorted to computing the number of extrema of the function within an interval (using the derivative and its proximity to zero) and dividing that by the length of the interval, but that isn't easy on the computer. (I use Python, and I couldn't find many low-pass filters for the data.)

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by needs to implement? Do you mean you simply need to report the "wiggliness". Also I would take wiggliness to mean the variance of your series (or intervals within the series.)

Comment: I need to find the 'wiggly' intervals, as those are text blocks. I'm using this to find blocks of text in a scanned document, and I found that this is the easiest way for the computer to 'see' deformed blocks of text on a sheet of badly-scanned paper.

Comment: I am not an expert in computer vision, but I would bet there are better and faster algorithms to do that.

Answer (score 2):

A moving standard deviation sounds like a reasonable thing to use... here is a toy example in poorly written untested poorly optimized pseudo-C, things may go out of bounds or not work as I expect, but you should get the general idea:

```
const int NPixelColumns; //The number of pixels columns
const int WindowSize; //The size of the moving window for the standard deviation
double BrightnessVals[NPixelColumns]; //Someplace to store your data initially
int startIndex; //Where the moving window starts
int lcv; //Generic loop control variable

for (startIndex = 0; startIndex++; startIndex < (NPixelColumns-WindowSize))
{
   int endIndex = startIndex + (WindowSize-1);
   double sum; //the sum of values in the windows
   double xbar; //the mean in the window
   double deltasq[WindowSize]; //the squared differences between the mean and the value
   double SS=0; //the sum of deltasq
   for (lcv = startIndex; lcv++; lcv <= endIndex)
   {
       sum += BrightnessVals[lcv];
   }
   xbar = sum/WindowSize;
   for (lcv = 0; lcv++; lcv < WindowSize)
   {
       deltasq[lcv] = pow(BrightnessVals[startIndex+lcv]-xbar,2);
       SS += deltasq[lcv];
   }
   printf("At step %i the moving SD is: %f", startIndex, SS/sqrt(WindowSize-1));
}
```

In R this kind of thing is a snap:

```
sdwindow <- function(start,end,data)
{
    return(sd(data[start:end]))
}
nsamp <- 1000 #The number of samples to look over
windowsize <- 10 #The size of the window to get the SD of
x <- rnorm(nsamp) #Sample data
start <- 1:(nsamp-windowsize) #starting points for the window
end <- (windowsize+1):nsamp #ending points for the window
doit <- Vectorize(sdwindow, vectorize.args = c("start","end")) #save me the trouble of figuring out mapply for the nth time.
doit(start,end,x) #generate the result
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! This is a lot more efficient than recursively counting minima/maxima within a set interval... I'll have to go and check it out.

Answer (score 1):

What about Moving Averages?

Edit: For calculating moving standard deviations, this is a quick and dirty way to do it in R:

```
n.x <- 1000
x <- cumsum(rnorm(n.x))
plot(x,type="l")
win <- 20
roll.sd <- as.vector(rep(NA,n.x))
for(i in 1:(n.x-win)){roll.sd[i] <- sd(x[i:(i+win)])}
```

I think quantmod has a build-in function for it. You could build, in a similar way, a moving average for first differences of the time series.

Comment: Perhaps moving standard deviations would be more informative.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the question, I thought he wanted to smooth the data, and was underwelmed by his current results. If he wants to extract the conditional volatility I would use GARCH, or squared logged differences as a first step.

Comment: How would I go about implementing a moving standard deviation? I'm not familiar with statistics (I'm studying theoretical mathematics at the moment), but I think that's exactly what I need. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Blender I've never actually calculated a moving stdev, but I expect that you could simply choose a window size (the number of data points to include in the stdev) and calculate a stdev at each point along the dataset. You would have to start half of the window length in from one end of the data, and stop half from the other end. Probably an easy calculation in a spreadsheet.

Comment: In the trading world a moving standard deviation is known as Bollinger Bands. A web query on this will generate thousands of hits.

Comment: You can look at the rollapply function in the zoo package.  And use sd as the function.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to find the correlation of the series of differences with the moving average of the series of differences using some scale for the moving average (for example, use a 10 point moving average as the scale). This way you can get an idea about how "wiggly" the series is at different scales. This tells you whether the series has a tendency to move back and forth or keep moving in the same direction.

If the correlation is reasonably negative that implies that it is wiggly, it goes one way then comes back near where it was before. If the correlation is zero then it's not wiggly, if it moves in one direction, it has no tendency to move back where it came from. If it's positive then you might call it "anti-wiggly", it has a tendency to keep moving in the same direction it has been moving in (it has lots of trends).

Repeat this at several different scales, say 2, 4, 8, 16, 24 ... data points, and then you can look at the graph.